# Saving output of aws-ssm run command to s3 bucket in a different region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-ssm

When I execute AWS SSM-Agent send-command on an instance in some region, for example eu-central-1, (but would like to make this work for instances in all regions)
I would like the output to be saved in an s3 bucket which is in us-west-2 (in the same account).
This is part of my python code:

```
response = ssm_client.send_command(
            InstanceIds=[instance_id],
            DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
            OutputS3BucketName='my-bucket',
            Parameters={'commands': [cmd],})
```

where *cmd* is the shell command I'm running, which is set before response.

The command is run successfully and I can see the output (truncated) in the ssm console.
However the output is not saved to the bucket. The bucket is empty.
Since the output is long I would like to save it to an s3.

Since the --output-s3-region argument is deprecated, how can I make sure that the output of this command is saved to the bucket which is in a different region than the instance?

Comment: The bucket region does not matter. What matters is the bucket policy of the target bucket and or the iam permissions of the instace profile: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ssm-output-s3-other-account/